# How do I get the value from this JSON?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Here is the JSON:

`[ RowDataPacket { name: 'Matt' } ]`

I need to extract the value 'Matt' to then update a value in a database, but stupid me is having trouble figuring out how to extract it.

Just for context, the json comes from this request:

```js
var currentName = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE password="' + authPass + '"';
userDB.query(currentName, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result)
});
```

Comment: Don't concatenate queries. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but I just need to know how to isolate the 'name' string value of 'Matt'

Comment: If you don't show the actual structure of the data, it's impossible to answer. I've closed this as a duplicate of a general question that explains how to access nested data.

Comment: It looks kind of like an array, but what is `RowDataPacket`?

Comment: I think you just want `result[0].name`

Comment: But if there are multiple users with the same password, you need to loop to get all the names.

Comment: Why are you looking up all the users with this password, anyway? When authenticating a user you should look up the name and then check the password.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't store plaintext passwords. You should use a hashing method with salt.